# Setting Screen Timeout on Ubuntu Using the Command Line

Tags: command-line, server, laptop, power-management

I'm running Ubuntu Server on a laptop. I want to set the timeout to 0 or close to that so that the screen will be off unless I wake it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this using `setterm -blank`

**Update**

This stopped working for me as the value got reset on reboots.

I instead [set](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters) the [kernel parameter](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html) `consoleblank` to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanted to logout idle users automatically to protect the local console, try "autologon".

```
$ apt-cache show autolog
Package: autolog
Priority: extra
Section: universe/admin
Installed-Size: 148
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Luis Uribe <acme@eviled.org>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 0.40-13.1
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7), cron (>= 3.0pl1-42)
Recommends: exim4 | mail-transport-agent
Filename: pool/universe/a/autolog/autolog_0.40-13.1_amd64.deb
Size: 28022
MD5sum: 043c4d4087b377e1934a5496a36fd03a
SHA1: 6b1255ea2fcb9d9115309134073308964c124e7f
SHA256: 42f5609fd698f1bb4d5c472494c5a1a34cddc5566fb2708ccfc9b3c5ef4f11f4
Description-en: Terminates connections for idle users
 Autolog terminates connections considered to be idle based on a large
 variety of parameters.
Description-md5: 709929c5c8e5f8913099fd425517dfb3
Homepage: http://gitorious.org/debian-packages/autolog
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
```

Comment: Thanks, but I just want to turn the screen off, leaving users logged in.